# Issue with Test Plan Migration - The value of field 'EndDate' must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM

Tags: azure-devops-migration-tools

I have moved all test cases from TFS to Azure DevOps and now I am running Test Plan migration with tool version 11.6.8 and I encountered an error.

Does anyone know how to fix this? Any help is appreciated.

My Test plan migration config:

```
"Processors": [
    {
      "ObjectType": "TestVariablesMigrationConfig",
      "Enabled": true
    },
    {
      "ObjectType": "TestConfigurationsMigrationConfig",
      "Enabled": true
    },
    {
      "ObjectType": "TestPlansAndSuitesMigrationConfig",
      "PrefixProjectToNodes": false,
      "Enabled": true,
      "OnlyElementsWithTag": null,
      "TestPlanQueryBit": null,
      "RemoveInvalidTestSuiteLinks": true,
      "FilterCompleted": false
    }
  ],
```

Here are the error:

```
[11:38:46 INF] Processor: TestPlansAndSuitesMigrationContext
[11:38:46 INF] Migration Context Start: TestPlansAndSuitesMigrationContext
[11:38:46 INF] TestPlandsAndSuitesMigrationContext: Plan to copy 30 Plans?
[11:38:46 INF] ===============================================================================================
[11:38:46 INF] ===============================================================================================
[11:38:46 INF] ===============================================================================================
[11:38:46 INF] ==      Suite Name: Bill 9 & Sanctions Release 1 Iteration 1     =============================
[11:38:46 INF] ==            Date: 2016/03/31                                   =============================
[11:38:47 INF] ==          Suites: 6                                            =============================
[11:38:47 INF] ===============================================================================================
[11:38:47 INF] ===============================================================================================
[11:38:47 INF] ===============================================================================================
[11:38:47 INF] == Plan[ 1/30] Suite[0/0] Cases[0/0]  - planid[463   ] | Process Plan Bill 9 & Sanctions Release 1 Iteration 1
[11:38:47 INF] ===============================================================================================
[11:38:48 INF] ===============================================================================================
[11:38:48 INF] ===============================================================================================
[11:38:48 INF] ===============================================================================================
[11:38:48 INF] ==      Suite Name: Hello TFS                                    =============================
[11:38:48 INF] ==            Date: 0001/01/01                                   =============================
[11:38:48 INF] ==          Suites: 1                                            =============================
[11:38:48 INF] ===============================================================================================
[11:38:48 INF] ===============================================================================================
[11:38:48 INF] ===============================================================================================
[11:38:48 INF] == Plan[ 2/30] Suite[0/0] Cases[0/0]  - planid[535   ] | Process Plan Hello TFS
[11:38:48 INF] ===============================================================================================
[11:38:49 INF] == Plan[ 2/30] Suite[0/0] Cases[0/0]  - planid[535   ] |  Creating Plan Hello TFS
[11:38:50 FTL] Error while running TestPlansAndSuitesMigrationContext
**Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.**Client.TestManagementValidationException: The test plan cannot be saved because some properties are not valid.

**EndDate: The value of field 'EndDate' must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.
StartDate: The value of field 'StartDate' must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.**

   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client.TestPlan.Save()
   at VstsSyncMigrator.Engine.TestPlandsAndSuitesMigrationContext.ProcessTestPlan(ITestPlan sourcePlan) in D:\a\1\s\src\VstsSyncMigrator.Core\Execution\MigrationContext\TestPlansAndSuitesMigrationContext.cs:line 747
   at VstsSyncMigrator.Engine.TestPlandsAndSuitesMigrationContext.InternalExecute() in D:\a\1\s\src\VstsSyncMigrator.Core\Execution\MigrationContext\TestPlansAndSuitesMigrationContext.cs:line 83
   at MigrationTools.Engine.Processors.MigrationProcessorBase.Execute() in D:\a\1\s\src\MigrationTools\Engine\Processors\MigrationProcessorBase.cs:line 45
[11:38:50 ERR] TestPlansAndSuitesMigrationContext The Processor MigrationEngine entered the failed state...stopping run
```

In AzDO process template, I have set EndDate and Start Date to "Set the initial value to the current date and time", but I still encounter this error.

It looks like the error is about saving TFS Test plan? Do StartDate and EndDate fields exist in TFS test plan as I can't seem to find them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure out the issue.  The test plan in TFS does not have StartDate and EndDate filled.  Someone with right right access filled in the fields in TFS and migration does not encounter this error anymore.